# ¿Cómo crear cuadrados de diferentes dimensiones y colores con ArrayList y StdDraw?. JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

Para el juego de hundir la flota estoy intentado crear cuadrado de diferentes dimensiones para simular los barcos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello, no estoy segura de donde debo crear los ArrayList si en el clase Main o en una clase aparte llamada Barcos. Además, no se por que continuamente me sale en error .add.

```
public class Barcos {
static private final String[] TIPO = { "verde", "morado", "gris", "azul" };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Tipo> barco = new ArrayList<Tipo>();
    barco.add(4, "verde");
    barco.add(1, "morado");
    barco.add(2, "gris");
    barco.add(3, "azul");

}
```

Comment: Pues es más POO-oriented tener instancias de una clase Barco con atributos de un barco. Depende de tu diseño. Y no sabemos qué error será el que obtienes

Comment: el codigo tal como lo pones no compila, asegurate de poner un [mcve]